# How do I get my Azure AD B2C Tenant whitelisted?

Tags: azure-active-directory

After creating my B2C Tenant in the legacy portal, when I navigate to the new portal I get the following error:

Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: 4645f854-4099-45b3-b2e5-b1b3c0e47353; Your tenant 'XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com' is not authorized to use b2c functionality. Please ensure your tenant is whitelisted"}

So how do I get my tenant whitelisted? I created a second tenant and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not have whitelisting constraint for B2C Tenants and the error message needs correction. Thanks for reporting and we will fix it. You are hitting the case where user trying to access is not a global admin for the tenant yet. Can you check if you are marked as global admin for the tenant and/or we may have a timing bug on our side? And if you are shown as admin please retry clicking on the Manage B2C Link on the tenants you already created.

Comment: I've got a weird situation. When I log into either azure portal with my Microsoft account (Hotmail email address), after logging in it shows my O365 email address in the upper-right corner of the portal.  

So, as you suggested, I checked to the tenant to see if my user was listed in the users page. I am listed but it shows my O365 email, not my Hotmail email (even though I logged in with Hotmail). That user does have the Global Admin role. I tried to add my Hotmail address as a user and it just says that this user already exists.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but another weird thing is that my new B2C tenant already has an application in it that I didn't add. The "Office 365 Management APIs" application is listed in the applications tab. I created a new tenant and it has the same thing. When I try to delete a tenant it tells me I can't because there are applications that depend on it. But I don't see any way to remove the application.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This issue is not related to the application observation you made. It is related to user access to the tenant context. Can you try the create B2C Tenant from a private browsing sessions (eg New Chrome Incognito window) and report the following: what is the user in both portals, and if user is admin. Based on that we can identify next steps.

Comment: OK, from a Chrome incognito window I logged into the legacy portal with my Hotmail account. I then created a new Ad tenant called "MyTestB2C" (with the B2C checkbox checked). Then I clicked "Mange B2C Settings" which opened the new Azure portal. Unfortunately I see the same "Access Denied" error on the blade. Under notifications I see a new error with this text: Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: 66e01672-d17f-45c0-920b-ac707c1f6a45; Your tenant 'MyTestB2C.onmicrosoft.com' is not authorized to use b2c functionality. Please ensure your tenant is whitelisted"}

Comment: Oh, and you asked me to report he user in both portals. In the legacy portal, upper-right corner of the page I see my Office 365 email address (not my Hotmail address that I used to log in). If I look at the users tab of the newly created tenant (still in the legacy portal) I see one user whose username is my Office 365 username. Over in the new portal in the upper-right corner of the page I see my name. Underneath that I see the name of the newly created AD tenant: MYTESTB2C.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble you are having and thanks for sharing the information. Can you now access https://portal.azure.com/MyTestB2C.onmicrosoft.com?Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin=true#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementBlade/id/MyTestB2C.onmicrosoft.com                              in a new browser session (preferably incognito window) with your user account which is an administrator on the tenant?

Comment: I see that the Portal has been updated but unfortunately I still see the same error when accessing that link you sent: Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: 967c178f-3e0d-427b-838f-bd12cd27c4e9; Your tenant 'MyTestB2C.onmicrosoft.com' is not authorized to use b2c functionality. Please ensure your tenant is whitelisted"}

Comment: We are still investigating to unblock you here. As per investigation so far the tenant seems to have been created fine. We suspect there is something interesting with the account being used here. While we try to figure that more, would it be possible for you to create another account, add that account as admin to the same tenant (MYTESTB2C), then use this new account to access the portal link? The new account could be a external MSA or <new user>@MYTESTB2C. Thanks for the patience here.

Comment: Alternatively since this specific case is becoming trickier a deeper engagement and sharing of information via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-support/ can help expedite to unblock you.  That way we can communicate in real time, share information  and narrow down the issue sooner. Again thanks for engagement and patience here.

Comment: Very interesting! I used a different MSA and added it to MYTESTB2C as a global admin, then, in a different browser, I navigated to the portal link and attempted to log in. It first gave me an error page saying something like "No subscriptions found for this account." So, just to be sure, I navigated to the link again and this time it brought up the blade! It looks like I am now able to see the MyTestB2C.onmicrosoft.com applications, policies, etc. in the new portal, which is great.

Comment: I am still interested in fixing my main MSA account if you think that's possible. Should I go ahead and create Support Request for that?

Comment: Our further investigation tells you originally had two accounts : one in Hotmail and another in outlook. The one in Hotmail is not a admin on the tenant and that is why you were not able to access. Our best guess is the tenant got created with the outlook account but for some reason the access happened using the Hotmail account. Please see if that helps and if not yes you take the support request route. We would be glad to help more to get your main MSA account working as well. Please keep sending the feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By using the Outlook account I am able to work around the issue for now. I don't think the tenant could have gotten created with the outlook account because I hadn't used that account for many months and it wasn't listed in the users of the tenant until you had me add it. I went ahead and created a support request to help me work through the issues that are preventing me from using my Hotmail MSA on the tenant. (It still won't let me add the Hotmail account as a Global Admin to the tenant and it still won't let me manage the tenant with the Hotmail or O365 accounts.)